# No se visualizan mis imagenes con Django

Tags: python, django

A la hora de ir a la tienda de mi ecommerce no se visualizan las imagenes, solo aparece el icono de como si hubiese una imágen, pero no la imágen en si.

Estoy utilizando Django como framework de desarrollo y en mis settings.py tengo el siguiente bloque de codigo:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
```

Por otro lado en mi tienda.py tengo:

```
{% extends 'tienda/index.html'%}

{%load static%}

{% block content %}

    <div class="row">
        {% for product in products %}
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img src="{{product.imageURL}}" alt="" class="thumbnail" >
            <div class="box-element product">
                <h6><strong>{{product.name}}</strong></h6>
                <hr>

                <button data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn  update-cart">Agregar al carrito</button>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="">Ver</a>
                <h4 style="display: inline-block; float: right;"><strong>${{product.price|floatformat:2}}</strong></h4>
            </div>

        </div>

        

        {%endfor%}
    </div>


{% endblock %}
```

Mi model de productos es el siguiente:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank = False)
    images = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

por lo que veo tu error se puede encontrar aqui:

```
<img src="{{product.imageURL}}" alt="" class="thumbnail" >
```

La manera correcta de insertar el src de un ImageField de Django es esta:

```
<img src="{{product.images.url}}" alt="" class="thumbnail" >
```

Donde images es el nombre del campo de tu modelo, en este caso como tienes habilitado blank=True y null=True podrias rodearlo antes con un if para saber si tienes una imagen y entonces mostrarla.